# Resumable upload with new file with special characters in name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm following the documentation to create a new upload session for a resumable file upload.

My request looks like:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/items/:folderId/children/:fileName/createUploadSession
```

This works when `:fileName` is something like `test.txt` or even `test 2.txt`. But throwing special characters in there like `test".txt` or `test%22.txt` cause the request to fail.

There no examples in the documentation on how to deal with special characters in this case, so is this supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File stored in OneDrive have similar [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247#naming_conventions)/restrictions to files stored locally. If you consider that OneDrive can sync to your local file system, it makes sense why this is the case.

In general, you should assume you cannot use any of these characters in your file names: 
`~` `"` `#` `%` `&` `*` `:` `<` `>` `?` `/` `\` `{` `|` `}`.

You can find the complete list at [Invalid file names and file types in OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, and SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-OneDrive-OneDrive-for-Business-and-SharePoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!